# What is the better choose for running background jobs in ROR

Tags: ruby, cron, ruby-on-rails-3.2, background-process

I see two gems [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever/) and [rufus-scheduler](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler/) for running cron jobs in ruby. Which is the better choose ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends.

Whenever is backed by the cron daemon of your system (so if your system has no cron daemon it won't work).

Rufus-scheduler is running inside of your Ruby runtime, it's not depending on a cron daemon, but if your Ruby runtime is going down, the schedules will be lost.

Please make sure you understand those differences, then decide, for yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Do you need to run background jobs or cron jobs? What is your frequency of scheduling jobs?

There are some RailCast episodes on the *background* jobs topic: [Starling and Workling](http://railscasts.com/episodes/128-starling-and-workling),  [Delayed Job](http://railscasts.com/episodes/171-delayed-job/), [Resque](http://railscasts.com/episodes/271-resque), [Beanstalkd and Stalker](http://railscasts.com/episodes/243-beanstalkd-and-stalker), [Queue Classic](http://railscasts.com/episodes/344-queue-classic). Some episodes are pre 2010 and RoR evolves fast...

Comment: I need to run cron jobs, time frequency is 1 hour.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of cooler options than u mentioned in your question

one is [Resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque/). [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/271-resque) is railscasts for same.
other one is [SideQik](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq). [Here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/366-sidekiq) is railscasts for same. Sideqik is new kid in the town and is doing pretty awesome.